# Silex .htaccess 403 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, silex

I'm getting a 403 forbidden error on my Silex API.

Here is the architecture of my project : [architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Q4r.png)

Here is my problem;

In /web/index.php, I have a get route that displays a welcome message. I Can read this message by calling example.com/api/2.0/web/, but not with example.com/api/2.0/ (which is what I want to do).

I have a .htaccess file that is supposed to redirect me from the root to /2.0/web/index.php but it doesn't seems to work.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have another .htaccess file in the /web directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you all for your help !

Comment: You can't update the apache conf ? Cause you can update VirtualHost to make web directory the root and move the .htaccess inside.

Comment: You should try to change the web directory root, so the only public accessible directory would be the web one. If you can't do that, can you try to change your rewrite rule (on the project dir, not the web one) with ```RewriteRule ^ web/index.php [QSA,L]```